# Unable to animate a div to the required position twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 8 divs which I can swap based on the values given in the respective drop down, As you can be seen in the image below:

[image]

However the animation is not working for the same div twice, as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa03f7g1/4/) . Say if I swap div 1 with div 4 and then I try swapping new div 1 with div 7, the div is animating bizzarely all over the page! Tried debugging it with firebug, all the values for animating were correct and the flow was also perfect. Still its causing this problem. Don't know whether I am missing something about the `animate()` method!! This is my HTML code :

```
<table cellspacing="30">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="img1" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop1" name="" class="drop">
                <option>1</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner1">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img2" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop2" name="" class="drop">
                <option>2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner2">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img3" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop3" name="" class="drop">
                <option>3</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner3">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img4" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop4" name="" class="drop">
                <option>4</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner4">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="img5" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop5" name="" class="drop">
                <option>5</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner5">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img6" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop6" name="" class="drop">
                <option>6</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner6">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img7" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop7" name="" class="drop">
                <option>7</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner7">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="img8" style="width:100px;height:40px;position:relative;">
            <select id="drop8" name="" class="drop">
                <option>8</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
            <img src="" width="120" height="40" id="img_banner8">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
  $(".drop").change(function () {
  var flag = false;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      var dropdown = document.getElementById('drop' + i);

      if (flag == true && source.value != i) {
          dropdown.value = i;
      }
      if (dropdown.value != 0 && dropdown.value != i && flag == false) {
          var a = i;
          var b = dropdown.value;
          var pos = i;
          var source_div = document.getElementById('img' + i);
          var source = dropdown;
          var destination = document.getElementById('drop' + dropdown.value);
          var destination_div = document.getElementById('img' + dropdown.value);
          var posDrop = Math.ceil(dropdown.value / 4);
          var posI = Math.ceil(i / 4);

          var modDrop = (dropdown.value % 4);
          var modI = (i % 4);
          if (modDrop == 0) modDrop = 4;
          if (modI == 0) modI = 4;
          if (modDrop > modI) {
              // move right
              var diff = modDrop - modI;
              $("#img" + i).animate({
                  left: +((diff) * 130) + "px"
              });
              $("#img" + dropdown.value).animate({
                  right: +((diff) * 130) + "px"
              });
          } else if (modDrop < modI) {
              // move left
              var diff = modI - modDrop;
              $("#img" + i).animate({
                  right: +((diff) * 130) + "px"
              });
              $("#img" + dropdown.value).animate({
                  left: +((diff) * 130) + "px"
              });
          }

          if (posDrop > posI) {
              //move down
              $("#img" + i).animate({
                  top: +(70) + "px"
              });
              $("#img" + dropdown.value).animate({
                  bottom: +(70) + "px"
              });
          } else if (posDrop < posI) {
              // move up
              $("#img" + i).animate({
                  bottom: +(70) + "px"
              });
              $("#img" + dropdown.value).animate({
                  top: +(70) + "px"
              });
          }
          flag = true;

      }
  }
  destination.value = pos;

  var temp_div = source_div.id;
  source_div.id = destination_div.id;
  destination_div.id = temp_div;

  var temp = source.id;
  source.id = destination.id;
  destination.id = temp;
});
```

Comment: There is probably an easier way to do this. Mind if I re-code it or something?

Comment: Please go ahead. Anything that solves the problem is helpful!

Comment: Do they have to be in a table?

Comment: @AdarshHegde FYI, there is a nice option called *Tidy Up* in jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created http://jsfiddle.net/qa03f7g1/27/. It may not be perfect but the code is simpler. I also removed the `div`'s from the table and positioned them absolutely.

```
$(".drop").change(function () {

    var $thisElem = $(this).parent();

    var swapIndex = $(this).children(":selected").val();
    var $swapElem = $("#img" + swapIndex);

    var thisPosition = $thisElem.position();
    var swapPosition = $swapElem.position();

    $thisElem.finish()
        .animate({left: swapPosition.left})
        .animate({top: swapPosition.top});

    $swapElem.finish()
        .animate({left: thisPosition.left})
        .animate({top: thisPosition.top});

    $swapElem.attr("id", $thisElem.attr("id"));
    $thisElem.attr("id", "img" + swapIndex);

});
```

Some problems:

- If on the same `left` position, there will be a delay as it animates each item to the same `left` position. This can be fixed with an if statement.
- You may want to set each option to it's corresponding location. This is easily done, comment if you want it done.

Comment: But can someone tell what was wrong with the code I posted. Just a bit curious to know what was going wrong!

Comment: @AdarshHegde I find it hard to read and understand (bad at reading other people's code) but I think you need to swap what is inside of the two ``td``'s and reset their ``left``, ``right``, ``top`` or ``bottom``.

Comment: okay that can be the reason because even thought I am moving the div's the td's aren't moving!
@Winestone Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that you use a wholly different approach? Rather then animating the divs directly, use an array to store information about which div is where and then re-render this part of the page every time a re-ordering has been made.

so say you've got an array like this:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

then pushing value 'x' on div 'y' leads to storing array[y-1] in z, setting array[y-1] to x-1, then setting array[x-1] to z.

Now you've switched them in your array in a stable manner.

Then re-render the table.

You could also add the array values to the divs with an data-arVal attribute if you like. This could be the basis of some nice animations.

Loop through the array like this

```
jQuery.each(array, function(i, arVal){
     //and set the values of the data attribute
     $('td:nth-child(' + i + ') div)'.attr('data-arVal', '' + arVal + '' );
});
```

data attributes are your friend. And jQuery each loops are way more handy and powerfull then for loops, I highly recommend you use the jQuery.each loop.

p.s. could be some typos here, didn't test what I wrote.